# Irrational numbers, decimal representation

Tags: number-theory, irrational-numbers, transcendental-numbers, decimal-expansion, transcendence-theory

Can this even be proved? (Or disproved?)

> Any irrational number without a 0 (zero) in its decimal representation is transcendental.

Not sure where to start on this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Wikipedia says,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_number)

> It has been conjectured that every irrational algebraic number is normal; while no counterexamples are known, there also exists no algebraic number that has been proven to be normal in any base.